# Paypal shopping cart with multiple items

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have developed a shopping cart and now I am stuck with paypal shopping cart form. I am trying to send multiple items with one single shipping, handling and tax fees. I have created following form but paypal gives me error `"Your shopping cart is empty."`

**Here is my code**

```
<form name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" ethod="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxx@xxxxx.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="5">
  <input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="30">
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="20">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Product 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_amount_1" value="60">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Product 2">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="4">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_amount_2" value="10">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay with Paypal"  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name provided for the amount is incorrect. Instead of

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_amount_2" value="10">
```

use

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="10">
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! why this field is not picking up by Paypal? `<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="30">` It should show $125 instead of $105

Comment: You're welcome. I am not sure why it isn't being picked up. I'd suggest creating a new question for that.

Comment: It looks like paypal does not support shipping cart wide

Answer (score 0):

The variable "handling_cart" should work.  It wouldn't work if you have your account set up not to allow transaction based shipping to override your profile shipping.  Double checking your shipping profile in your PayPal account and make sure you have it set to allow transaction based shipping to override your profile.